# dynamic gridview in not visible / not showing

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have set a dynamic gridview, which i want to use it in another form so i created it as

```
 public GridView gv = new GridView()
```

i have set in `Page_Load` properties of gv to

```
 gv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
 gv.Visible = true;
```

then i have another grid MyGridView which is static and have data in it. So when i try to copy all static gridview data to dynamic gridview data that is

```
gv.DataSource = MyGridView.DataSource;
gv.DataBind();
```

I am not able to view the Grid gv, why is it so? someone told me to add

```
 'Controls.Add(gv) in Page_Load
```

when i added its showing compile time error, that gv should be in a form with `runat=server`.
How can i put a dynamic gridview into a form with `runat=server`?

So my requirement is gv should be visible, how can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use some sort of holders for this try pannel

on aspx page create

```
<asp:Panel id="panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

on your backednd

do

```
panel1.Controls.Add(gv)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, after this i m able to see my grid in the form.

Comment: i have now one more problem, i have two webform wf1 and wf2, 
Now if i able to get data in wf1 gridview gv, but when i try to copy this data to another form like
wf2.gv1.DataSource=gv.DataSource;
wf2.gv1.DataBind();

and in wf2 i have again binded
gv1.DataBind();
myDiv.Controls.Add(gv1);

when i run and checked using breakpoints, i c there is no data in gv1, do you understand my question, can you tell me why, i am struck in this grids since 3 days

Answer (score 1):

Place a div with runat="server" into your page
then:

```
YourDivID.Controls.Add(gv)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, after this i m able to see my grid in the form.